# Elasticsearch filter with multi_match

Tags: elasticsearch, filter

I'm trying to write a query in ElasticSearch where I combine multi_match with filter for an id or a number og ids.

This is what i have so far:

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": {
                "multi_match": {
                    "query": "Kasper",
                    "fields": ["name", "first_name", "last_name"]
                }
            },
            "filter": {
                "term": {
                    "user_id": "ea7528f0-1b8a-11e8-a492-13e39bbd17cb"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The "must" part of the query works perfectly, and when I run it alone, I get two results.
When I pick out the "user_id" from one of the two results and adds the "filter" part of the query with that id, I get nothing.

What I really want to do is have something like in SQL where user_id in ('id1', 'id2'), so the filtering would be something like:

```
...,
"filter": {
    "terms": {
        "user_id": ["ea7528f0-1b8a-11e8-a492-13e39bbd17cb"]
    }
}
```

Did I misunderstand something here?

Comment: could you add the result of the bool query without the filtering? Thx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm guessing that this is because `user_id` field is treated as a [`text`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.2/text.html) and is analyzed. You should use [`keyword`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.2/keyword.html) type in this situation (you need just change the mapping of `user_id` field.

Another way (if you are on Elasticsearch 5+) you can search in [`keyword` subfield](https://www.elastic.co/blog/strings-are-dead-long-live-strings). Just try use below query:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "multi_match": {
          "query": "Kasper",
          "fields": ["name", "first_name", "last_name"]
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "term": {
          "user_id.keyword": "ea7528f0-1b8a-11e8-a492-13e39bbd17cb"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I only changed `"user_id"` to `"user_id.keyword"` in your query.

Comment: Great to hear that ☺

Comment: Great answer. I am using Elasticsearch version 7.5.2 and facing same problem. Save lot of my time.